# How do I use DATE_FORMAT inside my MySQL statement in Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to import rows of a csv file into a mysql table, I am using Python to do this.
Here's a snippet of my mysql statement from my python script:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO tbl_celebrants(id, name, DATE_FORMAT(birthday,'%m/%d/%Y'), address) \
         VALUES(%s , %s, %s, %s)"""
```

I am getting an error where it says
**ValueError: unsupported format character 'm' (0x6d) at index 60**

The Date format in my csv file is mm/dd/yyyy.  I have tried using %% in the **DATE_FORMAT( '%%m/%%d/%%Y')** in my python script as suggested by what I have read somewhere in this site but it did not work for me.  I appreciate any help and many thanks in advance.

P.S
Here's how I am executing the statement

```
for row in reader:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = """INSERT INTO tbl_celebrants(id, name, DATE_FORMAT(birthday,'%%m/%%d       /%%Y'),address) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
    cursor.execute(sql, row)
    cursor.execute("commit")
    cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's right, you should double all `%` char inside `DATE_FORMAT()` to didn't get them interpreted as prepared statement placeholder. But you're using the `DATE_FORMAT()` function in the wrong place, you should use it inside the `VALUES(...)` declaration, so to fix all the issue try that:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO tbl_celebrants(id, name, birthday, address)
VALUES(%s , %s, DATE_FORMAT(%s,'%%m/%%d/%%Y'), %s)"""
```

Comment: When I do this, I'm receiving an error

ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(birthday,'%m/%d/%Y'), address)    VALUES('id' , 'name', 'birthday', 'address' at line 1")

Comment: Freitas:

I edited my post where I included the whole snippet regarding on how I execute the sql statement.

Comment: @Paul Oops! Now I see that you're using `DATE_FORMAT()` in the wrong place, I've updated my answer accordingly, check if it works now. :)